# Centered text in fully clickable table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

This one is driving me mad, unfortunately I'm not very good in CSS yet.

How can I get a horizontally and vertically centered text-link into a table cell which is fully clickable?

I researched, tried several solutions, none of them worked. Here is my best approach so far:

**HTML**

```
<table class="dataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#">I wanne be centered!</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">Me too!</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.dataTable td a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dataTable td {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This one gives me centered text, but the link only covers the width of the cell, not the height. If I change the css for the link to display:inline-block, then the full cell is clickable, but the text is not vertically centered anymore.

I need both. Help!

Comment: Note that `td` is not a child of `.datatable` in your example.

Comment: @abiessu: the `td` is definitely a child of the `.dataTable`; *everything* within the `table` is a child.

Comment: Have you tried setting a fixed height (so a pixel height) on the parent `tr` element? Only then the child elements height can be set to 100%.

Comment: @DavidThomas:  I will admit that they are descendants, but not children.  However, if CSS does not distinguish the difference, I concede the point.

Comment: @abiessu: okay, I think I see what you mean, but it's worth noting that white-space matches all descendants, so the selector is appropriate to the use-case here. Had the OP used the child combinator then it would have been a problem, but as-is CSS doesn't really care about the 'depth' of the ancestry between the elements.

Comment: @MarkusHofmann: setting a height of 75px for the parent <td> makes the full cell clickable, but then, again, the vertical alignment of the <a> tag is gone :(

Answer (score 2):

i think you should remove this :

```
.dataTable td {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UrbwJ/)

Comment: I deleted the css, no effect. I also tried setting a fixed pixel height on the .dataTable tr as Markus Hofmann suggested, no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you want:

```css
.dataTable {
    text-align: center;
}

.dataTable a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Just for better visualization */
.dataTable td {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="dataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#">I wanne be centered!</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">Me too!</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If you want to increase `td`'s height, you should do it by modifying `a`'s height. Otherwise, the link will not occupy the whole cell's height. You can achieve that with `height` property or also with `line-height`.

```css
.dataTable {
    text-align: center;
}

.dataTable a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 5; /* To get a 5 text lines high cell */
}


.dataTable td {
  /* Just for better visualization */ 
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="dataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#">I wanne be centered!</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">Me too!</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

Wrap your text in a

```
div style="padding-top:5px;".
```

That will center it approximately.